# Is there a way to hold or suspend or break a condition until the other one has been met and then back to the normal in C?

Tags: python, c

I need help with the battery charger logic bits. I have power and state of charge(SOC) conditions with two current outputs (A and B) for the battery charger. Basically,

```
If power is < 100 output is A
If power is >= 100 output is B
```

at the same time

```
If SOC <20 output B
If SOC >=20 output A or B ???
```

The thing is that I want from the C function to get current:A until the battery SOC>=20%, then current: B is activated once SOC<20% to charge the battery. The issue is here current:B is active at the output once SOC<20 then it increases to 20 and then decreases and then increases decreases...charging state is always being around one instantaneously below 20 and instantaneously above 20.

I tried to use the break command but did not work

```
if (Power < 100)
    out = current A;
     while (SOC<20)
        break;
    out = current B;// until SOC reach to 80.
if (Power>=100)
    out = current B;
    if (20>=SOC>=80){
        break;}
    out=current A;
```

In a nutshell, I want to hold the charging mode statement(current B) until SOC reach to 80 when SOC <20 but at the same time power condition is also affecting the output as given above.

Comment: `break` exits the loop, so `while SOC < 20: break` is a no-op (either the loop is never entered, or it completes immediately).  You might want `while SOC < 20: continue` or `while SOC < 20: pass`, which would be a busy-wait until `SOC > 20`.

Comment: seems "to get current:A until the battery SOC>=20%" should be "to get current:A while the battery SOC>=20%"

Comment: You need to enumerate the possibilities and figure out what you want in each case, i.e. `Power < 100 && SOC < 20`, `Power < 100 && SOC >= 20`, `Power >= 100 && SOC < 20`, `Power >= 100 && SOC >= 20`, plus any others.

Comment: Step back from code, it distracts you from ideas for solutions. Write down a state table. If its output column looks simple, you can get away with simple conditionals. But if it has some kind of "memory", look up how finite state machines work and implement one.

Comment: so according to what you described, output A will increase power, but decease SOC, and output B will decease power, but increase SOC. is it right?

Comment: The issue is there SOC is a variable and I want to change the output with respect to SOC, but SOC is a dynamic variable. once it reduces below 20%, output B is activated but when it reaches 20% output switch to A again. I want to keep output B to increase SOC up to 50%.  The program needs to look at the SOC, if it is above 20 just give output A , when SOC is below the 20% output B is activated to charge the battery until it reaches 50%. The program needs to change the output according to the SOC trend, if it is increasing that means it is in charging mode and do not use output A use B.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description correctly, you may try the following control logic.

```
charge = 0
current get_current()
{
    if (SOC < 20)
        charge = 1;
    else if(SOC >= 80)
        charge = 0
    if(charge)
        out = B;
    else if (Power < 100)
        out = A;
    else
        out = B;
    return out;
}
```